# C# overloading resolution with hierarchical parameters

Tags: c#, methods, overloading, resolution

In the example I was expecting to get **Third** as output since class Third has an exact signature match to the Print call, but the output is **Second**. Why that happens?

```
class First
{
    public virtual void Print(string x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First");
    }
}

class Second : First
{
    public void Print(object x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Second");
    }
}

class Third : Second
{
    public override void Print(string x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Third");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sss = "lalala";
        Third t = new Third();    
        t.Print(sss);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> ...the set of candidates for a method invocation does not include
>   methods marked override (Section 7.3), and methods in a base class are
>   not candidates if any method in a derived class is applicable (Section
>   7.5.5.1).

Thus, overriden method in the `Third` is not applicable and `Second.Print(object)` hides base class implementation and becomes single candidate.

Comment: Note: You're linking to an earlier specification, the most recent version can be found here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7029

Comment: +1. It's worth pointing out (even though it basically says so in the spec) that this behavior is present only because the overload defined in the more-derived class is in less specific than the original; obviously, if the overload on `Second` took a `Foo` instead of an `object`, this behavior would not be present.

Comment: @Anthony I saw it was for earlier version, but didn't find C# 4.0 Specification online :( As 4.0 spec is exactly the same in this part - I've just quoted this. But it is good point anyway so everyone could know it is really same in 4.0 as well. Thanks.

Comment: @Adam If `Second` takes `Foo` instead of `object` - it wouldn't be applicable, so the second part of quoted rule wouldn't be applicable also.

Comment: @Ivan: Correct; like I said, the spec already states it, but it might be helpful to the OP to point out explicitly how this rule applies in his case and in what cases it would *not*.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Ivan's answer, I was surprised that you didn't mention getting a warning.

But then I noticed that you have 3 very similar, but not identical methods. The `Print` method in class `Second` takes an `object`, not a `string`, which is what the other two classes specify. So, the compiler thinks that you're introducing an overload to the `Print` method declared in `First`, not an [override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) nor hiding. And as mentioned in comments by other contributors, you see this behavior because the overload in the more derived class (`Third`) is more specific than the one in the base class (`Second`)

A look at the class diagram will help see this:

[image]

If you changed the signature in `Second` to take a `string`, your friendly compiler would have alerted you with:

> Warning    1   'Second.Print(string)' hides inherited member 'First.Print(string)'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.  Program.cs  40  21  C

and:

> Error  2   'Third.Print(string)': cannot override inherited member 'Second.Print(string)' because it is not marked virtual, abstract, or override  Program.cs  48  30  C

Take a look at this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fawty39.aspx) for more info.